# How to get the key names of a json file into an array in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to get the keys of a json file saved in a stage on snowflake into an array to be used in a procedure later on ?

Comment: can you add more context to reproduce?

Comment: Sure I can do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to answer when you do :)